# How to add small graphs to axis labels?

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have a List Line Plot of several lists. It looks ok. But the values at x correspond to a small graphs in a list, i.e. x=1 corresponds to the first graph I have in a list. The question now is if it is somehow possible to depict these small graphs at the axis, e.g. instead of / additional to having a "1" written on the x axis, could there be a depiction of the small graph? (It is a Graph object)?

Or, alternatively, is it possible to use something like Chart Label in List Line Plots?

Thanks a lot for your help!

(Sorry for not providing my actual plot and graphs here -- I have been trying for 30 minutes now to include my code here, but then I cannot submit my question because I am always told that my post is "mostly code" and I should write more details, even though the details were the same as now...)

Comment: Please show an example... cut from the web.

Comment: You can click the checkmark next to the answer to accept it. You will see it when you are logged in. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use Graphics as tick labels. Here is a simple example using regular polygones as tick labels:

```
graphlist = 
  Table[Graphics[RegularPolygon[0.1, i], ImageSize -> 10], {i, 3, 
    6}];
ListLinePlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 4], 
 Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range[4], graphlist}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That‘s brilliant! I don’t know how to mark your answer or how to close this question, but this is exactly what I have been looking for. Thank you!